# How to register Today widget for Cloud Kit notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, today-extension

Is it possible to do this as well as for the app?

I need to achieve something similar to WhatsApp. Today widget knows about changes from server. How can I do this?

Or is there a way to notify the widget about new changes in iCloud?